# JavaScript == operator not evaluating as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose

I have an array, called `conversations`, which contains an object:

```
[ { _id: 594b45b68cbad2077dbc84d5,
    created_at: 2017-06-22T04:21:10.178Z,
    created_by_user_id: '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1',
    sent_to_user_id: '5934fe100b557624207db665',
    __v: 1,
    users: [ 5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1, 5934fe100b557624207db665 ],
    messages: [] } ]
```

I have another value, `req.user._id` which is equal to `5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1` (the first element of the `users` array).

I am checking to see if `req.user._id` is equal in value to `conversations.users[0]`, and then returning something if it is.

```
if (convo.users[0] == req.user._id) {
  console.log("First element")
}
```

This should return true, and the `console.log` expression should run, but it's not.  What am I missing?

If I set the expression to `!=`, it evaluates the conditional.  So,

```
if (convo.users[0] != req.user._id) {
  console.log("First element")
}
```

works (`console.log("First element)` is run), as does

```
if (convo.users[1] != req.user._id) {
  console.log("First element")
}
```

I am using Express and Mongoose.

**EDIT**

I am running a `forEach` loop to iterate through `conversations` like so:

```
conversations.forEach((convo) => {
  if (convo.users[0] == req.user._id) {
    console.log("First element")
  }
})
```

**UPDATE**

I think I know why it's not working, but I don't know how to fix it.
`conversations` is an array like this:

```
[ { _id: 594b45b68cbad2077dbc84d5,
    created_at: 2017-06-22T04:21:10.178Z,
    created_by_user_id: '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1',
    sent_to_user_id: '5934fe100b557624207db665',
    __v: 1,
    users: [ 5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1, 5934fe100b557624207db665 ],
    messages: [] } ]
```

Specifically, `users` is an array of object ID references.
This is my `conversation.js` model:

```
var Conversation = mongoose.Schema({
    created_at: Date,
    users: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        }
    ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Conversations', Conversation);
```

It's being used in my `users.js` route like this:

```
var User = require('../models/user')
var Conversation = require('../models/conversation')

router.get('/member', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res, next) {
  Conversation.find({ users: req.user._id }).exec((err, conversations) => {
    conversations.forEach((convo) => {
      if (convo.users[0] == req.user._id) {
        console.log("First element")
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: You should be reading `convo.users[0]._id` right ?

Comment: I don't think so.  `convo.users` is an array equal to `[ 5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1, 5934fe100b557624207db665 ]`.

Comment: the problem is you are comparing 2 things you expect to be the same and they are not. can you tell us why they are not the same? what is the value of `convo.users[0] ` and `req.user._id`

Comment: also, a codepen would help so others could interact with the problem you're describing

Answer (score 1):

> The issue must be with you are comparing the string with mongoose
>   object id

---

`ObjectIDs` are objects so if you just compare them with `==` you're comparing their references. If you want to compare their values you need to use the `ObjectID.equals` method:

```
if (results.userId.equals(MongoObject._id)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had to update my post.  `conversations` is an array with more than one element, so I have to iterate through it in order to grab the `users` object (whose value is another array).

Comment: not issue you can use same condition inside your forEach loop

Comment: Ok, but I'm a little confused.  What values do `results`, `userId`, and `MongoObject._id` correspond to in my example?

Comment: just console the both values you will get idea , which one is simple string and which one is mongo id

Comment: Yeah, it's not working.  I also think you might be referring to `_id: 594b45b68cbad2077dbc84d5` with `MongoObject._id`, which is not what I'm after.  I'm only interested in the `users` object.

Comment: no I am not refering mongo object as _id: 594b45b68cbad2077dbc84d5

Answer (score 0):

cross check once with req.user._id that it is of any array type or directly having value.
i checked with below code its working fine

```
 var conversations = [ { _id: '594b45b68cbad2077dbc84d5',
    created_at: '2017-06-22T04:21:10.178Z',
    created_by_user_id: '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1',
    sent_to_user_id: '5934fe100b557624207db665',
    __v: 1,
    users: [ '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1', '5934fe100b557624207db665' ],
    messages: [] } ];
    var _id = '5934fd84d6ba4c241259bed1';
    if (conversations[0].users[0] == _id) {
  console.log("First element")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

conversations is and array, but you are trying to use it as an object
May be

```
if (conversations[0].users[0] == req.user._id) {

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, unfortunately.  Besides, `conversations` will be an array with multiple elements, so I need to be able to loop through the entire array.

Comment: Farid, I made from all ids strings and it worked for me  [test script](http://rextester.com/JGVIPA89156)

Comment: Ok, your script works, and I think I know why mine doesn't.  The elements in your `users` array are strings, whereas mine are object ID references.  So, my `conversation.js` model is
```var Conversation = mongoose.Schema({
  users: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
    }
  ]
});```
Then, I’m calling it in my routes file like so:
```Conversation.find({ users: req.user._id }).exec((err, conversations) => {
  conversations.forEach((convo) => {
    if (convo.users[0] == req.user._id) {
      console.log("First element")
    }
  })
})```